# discord.py How to edit a image in a embed?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Ok, so heres the problem. I wanted made a command that would in general just cycle through some data and images. So I did, but a problem I ran into was the fact that when I try to edit the image inside the embed it would throw an error. `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type File is not JSON serializable` 
This makes sense, but I can't find a way around this issue. Is there a way to make this JSON serializable?

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    file = discord.File('image1.png', filename="card.png")
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Random Embed')
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://card.png")
    msg = await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    file = discord.File('image2.png', filename="card.png")
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Title goes here', description='Description goes here', color=0x35363B)
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://card.png")
    embed.add_field(name='Stats:', value='Stats go here')
    await msg.edit(file=file, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't edit File once sent

You can edit the `image_url` from the embed for `set_thumbail` or `set_image`